# How to add jquery and stylesheet to my custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, javascript, css

I have created a custom module on frontend that is showing data from DB on now i want to add jquery and style sheet to my custom module front page.

I have tried like this through my layout xml but it is not including.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
  <layout version="0.1.0">   
     <reviews_index_index>   
        <reference name="root">   
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
        </reference>   
        <reference name="content">   
           <block type="reviews/index" name="reviews_index" template="reviews/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   
         <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>js</type>
                 <name>reviews/reviews.js</name>
            </action>
         </reference> 
    </reviews_index_index>  

 </layout>
```

Comment: Which file is not including? reviews.js?

Comment: i have updated the question yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JS is contained in the skin files, you need to use `addItem('skin_js', 'path/relative/to/jsdir.js')`. In your case, it would be like this:

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type><name>reviews/reviews.js</name>
</action>
```

Comment: it is here: skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\reviews

Comment: Ah. Well, then, you have to use addItem('skin_js')

Comment: like this:
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>reviews/reviews.js</name></action

Comment: @Xabby yep. Just like that.

Comment: Except don't forget the closing `>` after the action. Does that work?

Comment: <reference name="head">
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>reviews/reviews.js</name></action>
    </reference>

Comment: didnt work i put like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49260/discussion-between-tjons-and-xabby).